Why can't I replicate the results from this paper?
I'm trying to train a model to evaluate chess positions, following the methodology from this paper (note that the author presents several different architectures, but I'm only looking at the ANN with bitmap input). I've pretty much copied the setup exactly, with a few improvements such as a larger dataset and an input format with more information about the board state. However, my results aren't nearly as good as those in the paper - my MSE is around .04 vs the paper's .001. This may not seem like a lot but since values are normalized between [0, 1], and sqrt(.04) is 0.2, it's unacceptably high.
Basic info:

Dataset format: Two columns, one representing the board in FEN notation and the other with evaluation of the position in centipawns. Any evaluations that have forced mate or are above or below 5000 or -5000 are set to the corresponding max/min value.
The board is represented as a vector of length 776. There are 64 squares on the board and 12 different piece varieties (pawn, knight, bishop, rook, queen, king, multiplied by 2 for the two sides). Each square has a 12 dimensional vector and each position in that vector represents a piece and is marked with a 1 if that piece is present on the square and a 0 otherwise (this is one place I did things differently from the paper, as the author marked the square with a 1 if the piece was white and a -1 if the piece was black, but I tried this and saw no performance improvement). 64 * 12 = 768. I added some additional information that the paper didn't, such as two turn bits, four castling bits (white/black kingside/queenside), and two bits representing if either side is in check. 768 + 2 + 4 + 2 = 776. The paper only included the information about piece locations in its input representation.

The structure of the network is as follows:

776 unit input layer

2048 unit hidden layer (elu activation)

BatchNorm

2048 unit hidden layer (elu activation)

BatchNorm

2048 unit hidden layer (elu activation)

BatchNorm

1 unit output layer (sigmoid activation)

Optimizer: SGD with learning rate = 0.001, and Nesterov momentum of
0.7.


Here is my training code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
import chess
import chess.pgn
import os

chessData = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'chessData.csv'))
random_evals = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'rand_evals.csv'))
tactics = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tactics.csv'))
random_expanded = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'random_expanded.csv'))


max_value = 5000
min_value = -5000
WHITE_PAWN = 0
WHITE_ROOK = 1
WHITE_KNIGHT = 2
WHITE_BISHOP = 3
WHITE_QUEEN = 4
WHITE_KING = 5

BLACK_PAWN = 6
BLACK_ROOK = 7
BLACK_KNIGHT = 8
BLACK_BISHOP = 9
BLACK_QUEEN = 10
BLACK_KING = 11


PIECE_TO_POSITION = {'K': WHITE_KING, 'Q': WHITE_QUEEN, 'R': WHITE_ROOK, 'B': WHITE_BISHOP, 'N': WHITE_KNIGHT, 'P': WHITE_PAWN, 'k': BLACK_KING, 'q': BLACK_QUEEN, 'r': BLACK_ROOK, 'b': BLACK_BISHOP, 'n': BLACK_KNIGHT, 'p': BLACK_PAWN}

def nn_input(fen_string):
        board = chess.Board()
        board.set_fen(fen=fen_string)

        imboard = [[[0 for _ in range(12)] for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]
        squares = board.piece_map()
        for square in squares:
                x = chess.parse_square(chess.square_name(square)) % 8
                y = chess.parse_square(chess.square_name(square)) // 8
                piece = squares[square]
                imboard[y][x][PIECE_TO_POSITION[piece.symbol()]] = 1

        imboard = np.array(imboard, dtype='float32')
        imboard = imboard.flatten()

        white_turn = (1 if board.turn == chess.WHITE else 0)
        black_turn = (1 if board.turn ==  else 0)

        white_kingside_castle = board.has_kingside_castling_rights(chess.WHITE)
        white_queenside_castle = board.has_queenside_castling_rights(chess.WHITE)
        black_kingside_castle = board.has_kingside_castling_rights(chess.BLACK)
        black_queenside_castle = board.has_queenside_castling_rights(chess.BLACK)

        white_in_check = 0
        black_in_check = 0
        if(board.turn == chess.WHITE and board.is_check()):
                white_in_check = 1
        elif(board.turn ==  and board.is_check()):
                black_in_check = 1

        imboard = np.append(imboard, [white_turn for _ in range(1)])
        imboard = np.append(imboard, [black_turn for _ in range(1)])
        imboard = np.append(imboard, [white_kingside_castle for _ in range(1)])
        imboard = np.append(imboard, [white_queenside_castle for _ in range(1)])
        imboard = np.append(imboard, [black_kingside_castle for _ in range(1)])
        imboard = np.append(imboard, [black_queenside_castle for _ in range(1)])
        imboard = np.append(imboard, [white_in_check for _ in range(1)])
        imboard = np.append(imboard, [black_in_check for _ in range(1)])

        return imboard

def process_eval(evaluation):
        if(len(evaluation) == 1):
                return 0
        val = 0
        if('#' in evaluation):
                if(evaluation[1] == '+'):
                        val = max_value
                else:
                        val = min_value
        else:
                val = int(evaluation[1:])
        if(val > max_value):
                val = max_value
        if(val < min_value):
                val = min_value
        return (val - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)

def data_generator(filename, batch_size):
        while True:
                data = None
                if(filename == 'chessData.csv'):
                        data = chessData.sample(n=batch_size)
                if(filename == 'random_evals.csv'):
                        data = random_evals.sample(n=batch_size)
                if(filename == 'tactics.csv'):
                        data = tactics.sample(n=batch_size)
                if(filename == 'random_expanded.csv'):
                        data = random_expanded.sample(n=batch_size)

                fens = data['FEN']
                preprocessed_evaluations = data['Evaluation']
                X = np.array([nn_input(fen) for fen in fens], dtype='float32').reshape((batch_size, 776))
                Y = np.array([process_eval(evaluation) for evaluation in preprocessed_evaluations], dtype='float32').reshape((batch_size, 1))
                yield X, Y

model = Sequential([
        Dense(2048, activation='elu', input_shape=(776,)),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Dense(2048, activation='elu'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Dense(2048, activation='elu'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

learning_rate = 0.001 
sgd = SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.7, nesterov=True)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='mean_squared_error')

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=3, min_lr=1e-6)

batch_size = 248
steps_per_epoch = 1500
validation_steps = 1500
epochs = 100

train_generator = data_generator('random_expanded.csv', batch_size)
val_generator = data_generator('chessData.csv', batch_size)

model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=val_generator,
        validation_steps=validation_steps,
        callbacks=[reduce_lr],
        verbose=2,
)
model.save('model')

I'm surprised that the author was able to obtain the results he did with a dataset of only 3 million samples while I am struggling to get close with 13 million samples. I'm just wondering if there's something I missed or am doing completely incorrectly. Any advice is appreciated!

Have you looked at the code in the repository of the paper?

@Oxbowerce yeah but there was nothing related to the regression experiment in there, only classification.

Maybe email the author and ask if they could share their original source code.

Assuming the network architecture and training parameters are in line with the same (which they seem to be), have you tried comparing the datasets used? You could trying creating a dataset using the script in the linked reposity and use your training code to see if anything changes.
